# Best practice for using typescript const variable with class variables?

Tags: angular, typescript

Using this code (within an angular2 service), I can see it works, I am guessing the backticks allow for evaluation of this.heroesUrl and hero.id as if it were in a template:

```
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
    return this.http
        .put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => hero)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Question is, could I have just done this:

```
const url = this.heroesUrl + '/' + hero.id;
```

If so, is the former still preferred over the second given best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example uses es2015 template literals. In this case both of them are equivalent but template literals can be use to evaluate expressions inside strings.

For example if you'll like to add two variable inside a string:

1. ES5: `var sum = 'The sum is: ' + (a + b)`;
2. ES2015: `let sum =``The sum is ${ a + b}`

Comment: so should i not be using const and using let instead?

Comment: Well const and let are different. In the example I addressed template literals. You use const when you don't want the variable to be changed later on. For variables that are going to change, you use let which is the new alternative for var.

Comment: in my angular2 application, I have a few 'global configuration parameters'. in that case, should I be using something along the lines of const config = {'immutableproperty':'value', 'another property': 'config value''}?

Comment: Yes, it depends. If configuration on the app is not going to be change by the user (for example an admin) then you would want the variable to be immutable.